# How to compare two Lists in an efficient way?

Tags: collections

I have two List of objects. I am going to remove those objects from List1 that are in the List2 too. List 2 can have its own objects that List1 does not contain them. I am going to compare the objects inside the lists based on their IDs. I cannot use remove() or removeAll() methods and I am not going to create any set. What would be the efficient way?

Comment: Use remove or removeAll - Why can't you use them?

Comment: They do not work for some reasons.

Comment: Are the lists ordered in any way?

Comment: @hatchet No they are not.

Comment: Post your code, if they don't work it's not for "some reason" it's for a reason

Comment: It sounds like an assignment. Imagine two indexes on list1. One is where you're looking, one is where you're putting. How you advance them, and whether you move the item where you're looking to where you're putting depends on if the item in list1 where you're looking exists in list2.

Answer (score 0):

You must overwrite the `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods in your element classes, in order to be able to use `removeAll()` based on object equality. See the Java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) for a discussion on how to implement these methods.

Comment: ...if Java is what the OP is using.

Comment: I am trying to use this: return  Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(list2, new Predicate<Object>() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(Object object) {
                return !list1.contains(object.getId());
            }
        })); but it does not work.

Comment: Update your question instead of commenting here.